# On Ctrl+C, kill the current command but continue executing the script

Tags: bash, shell, signals, trap

I have a bash script, wherein I execute a line, sleep for sometime and then `tail -f` my log file to verify a certain pattern is seen, I press ctrl +c to get out of `tail -f` and then move to the next line till the bash script finishes execution:

Here is what I have done thus far:

```
#!/bin/bash


# capture the hostname
host_name=`hostname -f`


# method that runs tail -f on log_file.log and looks for pattern and passes control to next line on 'ctrl+c'

echo "==================================================="
echo "On $host_name: running some command"
some command here

echo "On $host_name: sleeping for 5s"
sleep 5

# Look for: "pattern" in log_file.log
# trap 'continue' SIGINT
trap 'continue' SIGINT
echo "On $host_name: post update looking for pattern"
tail -f /var/log/hadoop/datanode.log | egrep -i -e "receiving.*src.*dest.*"


# some more sanity check 
echo "On $host_name: checking uptime on process, tasktracker and hbase-regionserver processes...."
sudo supervisorctl status process


# in the end, enable the balancer
# echo balance_switch true | hbase shell
```

The script works but I get the error, what needs to change/ what am I doing wrong?

```
./script.sh: line 1: continue: only meaningful in a `for', `while', or `until' loop
```

Comment: also potentially relevant to visitors of this page: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163561/control-which-process-gets-cancelled-by-ctrlc

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `continue` keyword doesn't mean whatever you think it means. It means continue to the next iteration of a loop. It makes no sense outside of a loop.

I think you're looking for

```
trap ' ' INT
```

Since you don't want to do anything upon reception of the signal (beyond killing the foreground job), put no code in the trap. You need a non-empty string, because the empty string has a special meaning: it causes the signal to be ignored.

Comment: Or `trap : INT`

Comment: Also note that the trap must be before the line you need to break

Comment: @AmirUval not necessarily. It needs to be _executed_ before the line you want to break

Answer (score 1):

The error arise due to `trap 'continue' SIGINT`. From `help trap`:

> ARG is a command to be read and executed when the shell receives the
>   signal(s) SIGNAL_SPEC

So your script try to do `continue` command when receive `SIGINT` call but the `continue` is used in loops only.