# bash - stop a command within a loop but continue the loop

Tags: bash

I'm running a loop like this:

```
for ip in 10.0.0.1 10.0.0.2 10.0.0.3; do traceroute $ip; done
```

I want to be able to kill the current traceroute when it gets boring (and before its 30-hop max), and move on to the next one. But when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, it kills the whole `for` loop.

I guess what I need is either a way to end the current `traceroute`, or to send the loop a `continue`.

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184124/on-ctrlc-kill-the-current-command-but-continue-executing-the-script) and [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163561/control-which-process-gets-cancelled-by-ctrlc) are doing a similar thing, but in more complicated situations. Is there a reasonable way to do this when just running stuff from the prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [trap](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Trap_statement):

```
trap "echo ctr+c pressed" INT TERM;for ip in 10.0.0.1 10.0.0.2 10.0.0.3; do traceroute $ip; done
```

Comment: Ah, that does just what I wanted! The link is useful, but can you explain how it works here?

Comment: Read the fine manual or use google. There are a tons of paper about this.

Comment: I do appreciate the answer. Just trying to encourage the "Provide context for links" advice from https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer